# Patch 1.05 Data folder not found

Tags: steam, pillars-of-eternity

Steam just updated my game with patch 1.05 on starting the game I'm getting this:

[image]

There is no such folder :\

Answer (score 1):

There is a folder called EmptySteamDepot

[image]

Rename this folder to PillarsofEternity_Data and it fixes the problem.

[image]

Game now starts fine.

Comment: The recently sent out kickstarter update (#95) goes into further detail about this issue, but I'll summarize: This occurs in non-standard game install locations. Renaming like Paul demonstrates here should resolve the issue, but if it doesn't you can use Steam's Verify Integrity of Game Cache (right click Pillars of Eternity, click properties, click local files tab, click Verify Integrity of Game Cache).